# How to Add text in current RichTextBox text WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I Want to add some text to my richtextbox.

**Example** Consider I have one Richtextbox and its text is "Uzair" and now I want to add "Ali".
   `string myText = "Ali"

    RichTextBox.Text += myText`

I don't know why there isn't a Text property of RichTextBox in WPF
Is there any alternative to `RichTextBox.Text` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `AppendText` to add text to your `richtextbox`.

```
RichTextBox.AppendText("ALI");
```

Comment: Thanks  
Is there any other way to do that (Just for Knowledge).  
and why there is no Text property?

Comment: List of the methods is here in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In the remark they mentioned because of the better performance they have append check this also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx